# Is there a way to view the Chrome DNS cache?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, dns, browser-cache

Just like in Windows we can view the dns cache by `executing ipconfig /displaydns`, is there a way to view the DNS cache of Chrome?. In `chrome://net-internals/#dns`?

> [image]

We can see the button "Clear host cache" to flush the DNS cache, but there is no option to view it.